Should I use withContext(Dispatchers.Main) in my code?
While collecting stateFlows in Android, something stuck in my mind.
How should I write my code?
    private val _fetchAgent = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Agent>>(Resource.Loading)
    val fetchAgent: StateFlow<Resource<Agent>> get() = _fetchAgent.asStateFlow()

    fun fechAgentFromNetwork() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _fetchAgent.value = networkRepository.getAgentsRepo()
        }
    }

  private fun collectAgent() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            viewModel.fetchAgent.collect { resource ->
                when (resource) {
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            binding.progressbar.visibleProgressBar(true)
                        }
                    }

                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        // Verileri işleyin
                        val result = viewModel.manipulateRawData(resource.value.data)
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            with(binding) {
                                progressbar.visibleProgressBar(false)
                                mainRecyclerView.adapter = AgentListAdapter(result)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        // Hata durumunu göster
                        showErrorMessage(HomeContants.ERROR_MESSAGE)

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

Should I write it like in the example I provided, or should I use:
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{
...
}

and run all the code on the main thread?
I believe it makes sense to collect a Flow on an IO thread. What are your thoughts on this, including the reasons behind your opinions? Thank you for your answers!

It doesn't make much sense since in UI layer you just want to consume the state as is and display it. View layer should not be responsible for offloading jobs to async dispatchers.

Is networkRepository.getAgentsRepo() a suspend function or a blocking function? If your code doesn’t have direct blocking function calls in it (and it shouldn’t if you’re using modern code libraries) then you shouldn’t be messing with specifying dispatchers whatsoever. Exception to the above would be if you have big CPU intensive calculations to do.

If you're constantly needing to offload back to the main thread, you should just run this code on the main thread.  It will perform much worse constantly swapping threads than it would performing on a single thread, and lessen the risk of race conditions or sync issues (where a redraw gets half the new state but not all of it because this thread hasn't finished yet).  Here you would be on the IO thread for literally one type check, then going to the UI thread.  Avoid that.
What should be done on the IO thread is parsing and processing of data.  If you want to make a network request, parse a JSON response, and put the data in the database-  that's a perfect IO or background thread task.  Taking data that's already local and displaying it is a UI thread task,.
